# How would you factor out/simplify something like this: $((13x)^2-2^{y+4})/(x^2-2^y)$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, factoring

How would you factor out/simplify something like this: $$\frac{(13x)^2-2^{y+4}}{x^2-2^y}\ ?$$

Answer (score 0):

Rewriting

$$\frac{169x^2+16\cdot2^{y}}{x^2-2^y}=\frac{16(x^2-2^y) + 153x^2}{x^2-2^y}=16+\frac{153x^2}{x^2-2^y}$$

Comment: True! Is this the only way to factor? Any way to factor this in a form such as $(mx)^2-2^{y+n}$ ? Or even something without a "remainder" or denominator as it were (hope that makes sense)?